# how can i process the ipod library audio file raw data while it playing

Tags: cocoa-touch, audio, media-player, ipod

After i get the audio file's URL in ipod library with the MPMediaPickerController. Now the question is i want process the file's raw data before it's played. what shoud i do ??

N.B. In the MPMediaPickerController Reference have a fowllow addtion explain.

The URL has the custom scheme of ipod-library. For example, a URL might look like this:
ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=12345
Usage of the URL outside of the AV Foundation framework is not supported.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “process” the file? What do you want to do to it?

Comment: I want to get the PCM raw data from this file ,so i can add some sounds effect on the song.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AVURLAsset from the URL and from that an AVAssetReaderOutput; with this you can get CMSampleBuffers which have the "raw data" that you want.